# Docker port binding with Websphere Liberty and SpringBoot Rest Application

Tags: rest, spring-boot, docker, websphere-liberty

I'm facing a problem with a springboot application that provides some rest endpoints and runs on docker, builded upon websphere-liberty:springBoot2 image.
Let's say the spring app runs on port XXX, everything runs fine and i am able to reach the endpoints only if i bind the docker public port to the SAME value XXX , BUT if i want to use some different public port, say YYY, i reach the websphere pages on http://localhost:YYY, but the endpoint does not work and i obtain a page of Liberty that says "Context Root Not Found".

In other words, with springboot builded with server.port=XXX on application.properties, i obtain this:

> docker run -p XXX:XXX ....
>       =>  http://localhost:XXX              => spring "Whitelabel" error (as expected)
>       =>  http://localhost:XXX/myendpoint   => myendpoint reachable
>
> docker run -p YYY:XXX ....
>       =>  http://localhost:YYY              => websphere "Welcome to Liberty" page
>       =>  http://localhost:YYY/myendpoint   => myendpoint NOT reachable

I've tried adding "EXPOSE XXX","EXPOSE YYY:XXX","EXPOSE XXX:YYY" in the docker file but nothing has changed.

Why??? Any help is appreciated... Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should override the definition of the default virtual host, list off the canonical ports + the listening port + the port you expose when you `docker run`

```
<virtualHost id="default_host">
    <hostAlias>*:80</hostAlias>
    <hostAlias>*:443</hostAlias>   
    <hostAlias>*:your-bound-port</hostAlias>
    <hostAlias>*:your-exposed-port</hostAlias>
</virtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you @covener ! I had put on standby this issue and now i go back to it after two weeks. After a bit of struggle i realized that i was putting "use-default-host" to false. Anyway, your help has been essential. Thanks!